# Iterative Logarithm in Recurrence Relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, logarithms, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Anyone Could describe me How we can solve this recurrence relation?

$T(n) = T(\log n) + O(1)$

$T(1) = 1$

a) $O(\log n)$

b) $ O (\log^* n) $

c) $ O (\log^2 n) $

d) $ O (n / \log n) $

> Our TA Solution: she say, this is iterative logarithm and the answer would be (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\log^* n$ is defined by:

$$ \log^* n = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if }n\le 1 \\ 1+\log^* (\log n) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

That looks very much like your recurrence, modulo a constant term (except your recurrence looks like it needs some implicit rounding somewhere in order to make sure you reach the base case).

The TA is right that your $T$ is also $O(\log n)$, but that is not the *best* bound among the options. In fact $T$ is in *each* of the 4 possible complexity classes, but $O(\log^* n)$ is the tightest one.

Comment: would you please add some detail about "but that is not the best bound among the options" which one is more correct?

Comment: @nini: Look at the last 6 words in the answer.

Comment: can i ask, how you find the tightest one? i think for this we shoud have omega and big o ? am i wrong ?

Comment: @nini: I'm wondering if you even read the answer. Don't you see the similarity between the definition of $\log^*$ and your $T$? If the additive term in the $T(n)$ case were $1+O(1)$ instead of merely $O(1)$ (which might be 0), then it would be a simple matter to prove that $T=\Theta(\log^*)$.

Comment: Dear Henning, you are so clever, i know. i'm not so clever and expert. i just say, if we dont know about this logarithm, is there any other way to solving this recurrence?

Comment: @nini: No, if you pretend the solution doesn't exist (or refuse to contemplate it), then there is no way of solving the problem.

Comment: i see lots of recurrence like T(n-1)+O(1) or others, and solve it with guess method or substitution method. but i think we learn iterated logarithm to solve it. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help (for sake of argument assume $O(1)=1$):
$$T(1)    =  T(0) + 1$$
$$T(e)    =  T(1) + 1 = T(0) + 2$$
$$T(e^e)  =  T(e) + 1 = T(0) + 3$$
$$T(e\uparrow\uparrow n) = T(0) + n + 1$$

$$log^*(e\uparrow\uparrow n) = n$$

(where $\uparrow\uparrow$ is tetration).

Now take $O(1) = 0$, so $T(n) = O(log^*(n))$